# Map one field value to other field using Gson on condition like if first one is null or having value zero

Tags: parsing, gson

I am trying to map one field value to other if that is null or zero. I am using Gson library to parse Json. Is there any way to map values on condition base. I tried using JsonAdapter where I can put condition for that field but unable to find out solution how to get other field value there to put in that.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own deserializer implementing `JsonDeserializer<Element>` something like below according json response-

```
class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Element> {

    @Override
    public Element deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jobject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject object = jobject.get("key").getAsJsonObject();

        if(object == null){

        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Usage -

```
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Element.class, new CustomDeserializer());
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Comment: I created custom deserializer but my requirement is to put some value from the response if it null.

Comment: public class CustomOfferIdParser implements JsonDeserializer<Integer> {
     private int mPassive_id=11;

    @Override
    public Integer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                               JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        return json.getAsInt() == 1 ? mPassive_id: json.getAsInt();
    }
}

Comment: fun parseData(){
            val string = "{name: \"John\", passive_id: 31, id: 1, email: \"vshpangotra@gmail.com\"}"
            val userModel = Gson().fromJson(string, UserModel::class.java)
            Log.e("userModel", userModel.toString())
        }

Using the method to parse the data and customDeserializer overriden method to return value. Is there anyway to get the passive_id in customDeserializer class to enter into Id.